# Custom Dialogbox background image is not shown clearly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-component, dialog

i have made a simple dialog activity in android for learning purpose and make a custom dialogbox and shown in another activity all is going well ,the only problem is background image i have put doesn't shown in whole Dialogbox background..but it also show a white background as a corner,Here i have put a screen so that my problem will be clear..!

my image:

[image]

My code is:

**dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dilog"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_close_38" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#202425" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/usernm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_box"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Please enter your client number"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pwd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_box"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Please password"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#6e6d6c"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text="Remember me" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chk_login"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_small"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#f6f1eb"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post ur xml code.

Comment: i have olready posted...!

Comment: k dude...u have solved ur prob..hav a good day.

Comment: oh...thanx bro...same to u..:) pratikbhai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call in your dialog constructor:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: @Dimmerg-its working fyn..but now problem is my activity focusing 2nd tym when i run program 1st tym..! :(

Answer (score 2):

try to add style on your **res/values/styles.xml**

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Panel">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
       </style>
    </resources>
```

and apply these style to your dialog like below code:

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomePage.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popupaddcustomer);
 dialog.show();
```